# Run another exe file from a batch file with filename parameters through a loop

Tags: batch-file, parameters, cmd, iteration, exe

im new to writing batch files.

I am trying to run an exe file over number of files in a folder with a specific extension (.class) with a program parameter. i.e. if i were to manually run it over a single file the following command in command prompt would do:

```
jad -sjava FileName.class
```

that line produces a FileName.java in the same directory.

But my batch file doesn't work and I cannot figure out why. There are no errors but it just doesn't work. Following is my batch file:

```
@echo off
CD ".\ClassFiles"

for /r %%i in (*.class) do (
START "" "jad" -sjava %%i.class
)

SET /P uname=Press enter to exit:
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to decompile a lot of class files - use another tool - i use jd-gui, and that will export a whole jar of class files into a zip of java files for you
  https://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&

Comment: thanks for your reply, out of curiosity I'd like to know where i went wrong. I narrowed down my question. basically the problem is passing the parameters to the exe file in the line starting with "START" as in the command i did for a single file.

Comment: have you tried removing @echo off to see that it is actually generating the commands you want? I just tinkered with you r code, and a dummy bat file named jad.bat containing `@echo %1 %2`, and that seems to work fine, echoing -sjava and the full path of the file found in the dir